# Listview Item not showing after clicking on list item

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have created a list in Xamarin and when we select item without scrolling list then everything is fine and when we select item after scrolling list then after clicking list item
lost. Actually list item is exist but not showing and error comes after clicking on list item is :

**V/AutofillManager(10440): requestHideFillUi(null): anchor = null**

Here is the code:

```
        private ObservableCollection<BlackListNewModel> _DeviceList = new ObservableCollection<BlackListNewModel>();
        public ObservableCollection<BlackListNewModel> DeviceList
        {
            get { return _DeviceList; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _DeviceList, value); }
        }
        DeviceList.Add(new BlackListNewModel
                    {
                        DeviceImage = "android",
                        Name = item.hostname ?? "Android",
                        Address = item.mac_address,
                        Id = item.id,
                        DeviceType = DeviceType.Android,
                        IsChecked = false,
                        IsNotChecked = true
                    });
```

Comment: Could you please show the full exception messages? In addition, can you debug it to find which line cause the error?

Comment: Actually there is no error when we debug the app, Only problem is everything is fine until list scroll and after scrolling list when we click on checkbox for adding list item then it blank that item.

Comment: Can you provide a small sample which can reproduce the problem?